# Python3 EOFError After 8 Consecutive Inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, eof, python-idle

I'm not sure if I'm missing something here.

After 8 consecutive input statements my python 3 program (running in x64 Windows 7) crashes with an EOFError whenever it is run in command line/console. That is to say, after I've pressed [return] 7 times, it prints out the text for the input statement then immediately fails, not giving me a chance to input anything. The same issue occurs if I enter text for any/all of the inputs, with no change to the behaviour. This problem originated in a larger project however I've isolated it to this code:

```
#! py -3
input("1")
input("2")
input("3")
input("4")
input("5")
input("6")
input("7")
input("8") # The program crashes after the "8" is printed
input("9")
```

The program works flawlessly when executed in IDLE however whenever it is run in command (using Python 3.4.3) the below error occurs:

```
...
6
7
8Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    input("8")
EOFError
```

Is the program running out of memory or something related to that?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

EDIT: Added extra detail regarding platform

Comment: Are you using a pipe instead of keyboard input? I'm observing the same exact behaviour when you pipe through too few lines for all `input`'s to ingest.

Comment: @pawroman Unfortunately I can't say I know what a pipe is. However, I am using a keyboard input. The program crashes whether I input some text for each input or just press enter to skip it. I'm running this on Windows (I'll update my question). It seems like this behaviour is too particular to be caused by multiple different things, so maybe our problems are linked...

Comment: This seems very strange then. Have you tried a different machine? Are you sure that the program does not modify `sys.stdin` in any way? You might also try out a different terminal/console program.

Comment: @pawroman I haven't had the opportunity to test it on another machine myself, however my friend does not see the same error when running the same program. Unless something is happening behind the scenes no, I am not modifying sys.stdin. I will try using something else, however Windows Powershell exhibited the same behaviour.

Comment: Can you reduce you program to a minimal size that produces the error but is small enough to post?

Comment: The code included in the original question did cause the error. I have since installed a clean copy of Python and it's working now, suggesting that it was an issue with a library or something similar.